# Is it fair to use order of received emails to select the winners

Tags: email, outlook, smtp, gmail, imap

One organisation in our country used order of received emails to select the winners. Thousands of people sent email at the same time. They are not transparent enough to tell me the exact time of my email received.

So First Question is :
Is that possible for a mail server to receive emails at exactly same time?
If yes, then how will it order the emails received at the same time. Will it only depend on the settings of mail client like outlook ?

Second Question:
As it was mentioned that they will consider emails only 10:00am onwards. I sent email exactly at 10:00am. I got their automated out of office reply and around 300 more people get it. My wife sent email one second later, she didn't get the Automated out of box reply. So can this slow my email to reach the mail client ?

Third Question:
Can someone provide more technical reasons to explain that "Order of received emails" is not fair way for lottery. and How can this give intentional and unintentional advantage to some people.

Thanks,
Kind Regards..

Comment: It is not fair.  Users source email server can queue it for quite some time before sending it to the remote server.  The remote SMTP server may or may be multithreaded or multihomed, which means that within any given tolerance, probably messages could arrive "simultaenously."  Also,what received time?  There are a multitude of dates associated with email.  The Date header, the Received time, the INTERNALDATE (for IMAP), etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not actually a programming question.

Comment: Max, Thanks for your input. I will change the description so that it will look more programming question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to pretend this is a programming question, namely, how to program your way to the prize. The easiest way should be to write a custom SMTP client in, say, about 50 lines of ruby, python, c or java. The client should create 5000 threads, and in each thread it waits until 9:58:40, then opens an SMTP connection to the prizegiver's SMTP server, sends EHLO, MAIL FROM, RCPT TO, DATA, the body, then waits until 10:00:00, then sends CRLF.CRLF and repeats a few times without waiting. Very simple, the only thing to watch out for is that some of the 5000 connections will fail because the receiver hasn't enough capacity.

The result is that starting about a minute before the competition starts you occupy most or all of the receiver's mail server capacity. In the first second, you submit 5000 messages and noone else has a chance to submit any. In the following seconds, you submit 5000, 10000 or 15000 more, just in case the receiver's clock is off by a little.

FWIW, I have once delivered around 5000 messages in one target second (an announcement that should reach people at the same time). It worked. I had to use three regular mail servers, though, and only 1500 destinations per server.